# Help with using 4N25 optoisolator

Tags: opto-isolator

I'm using an open collector comparator LM339, and I want to isolate V2 from the circuit by a 4N25 optoisolator. I want V(out) to change its state from at least around 1V or less up to 10V. But I get the following result in LTspice IV where Vout swings between 8.5V to 10V:
[image]

I cannot change R8, and I want LED to blink for every pulse. I might be using the coupler wrong way. I also noticed R7 also have big effect on the coupler; if I set it to 10k it doesn't work at all.

How can I modify this circuit so that Vout can swing more(from around 1V to 10V) and LED blinks?

Edit:

Suggestion from a comment:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

[image]

Comment: Have you considered a modest pull-down resistor?

Comment: Do you mean before D1? If so I tried it doesnt work

Comment: What about this suggested edit from a comment? Does it work or not?

Comment: suggested edit which one?

Comment: I meant directly across the output, to pull it down to GND unless it gets pulled up.  But I see below that you found an answer that works.  That's great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others suggested and you've changed your schematic to get rid of the LED in the output ....here's a simple modification that should provide your required output voltage swing.

Choose an appropriate PNP to sink your required current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhrC6F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could also use a FET to achieve the same result.

Comment: I followed you suggestion it works now. I also increased R7 to 10k for low current sinking. What do you think?

Comment: Since your VCC is also 10 V I'd suggest you are making R7 too high at 10k. This is reducing the LED (both) current to less than 1 mA. While you can certainly operate the 4N25 at this current level you will get closer to an edge where it won't work as it gets really cold. I'd suggest you want to make the current in the 1-2 mA range. At this current you will need a very high efficiency indicator LED to provide reasonable brightness.

Comment: @JackCreasey I set R2 to 5.6k. One more thing I need up to 120Hz but after around 60 Hz pulses becomes like sawtooth at output. I mean rising edges becomes like ramp. Reducing R3 makes better. But what is the safe minimum R3 I can use do you think? thanks

Comment: @JackCreasey Setting R3 to 2.2k for example gives good results. Is there a reason why you chose 20k?

Comment: R2 (on my circuit) is the I(CBO) shunt. It could be anything from MOhms to say 0.6 / (0.5 * I(LED) * CTR)). So I'd not suggest less than 6.2k Ohms with LED current of 1 mA.

Answer (score 6):

You have two things that need changing:

1: A 4N25 only has what is called a Current Transfer Ratio of as low as 20% ([4N25 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf)). This means that the current out of the photo-transistor may be as little as 1/5 of the current the is injected into the LED. You have less than 2 mA being put into the LED, but require about 10 mA from the 4N25 phototransistor.

Also from the data sheet the absolute maximum current you are permitted to inject into the LED is 60 mA. You may be able to inject enough to get the output current you require, but it would probably be better to put amplification after the optocoupler.

The [LM339](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosbj3e/snosbj3e.pdf) is only guaranteed to be able to sink 6 mA (typically 16 mA), so it will have difficult time directly driving the 4N25 with a high current.

2: You have the output LED on the ground side of the photo-coupler. This will prevent the output (Out) going below about 2 V (LED voltage plus the voltage across the photo-coupler). Again if you put a transistor after the photo-coupler to amplify the current it should be no problem to meet your requirements.

You could also do something like using two couplers with the LEDs in series driven by about 40 mA, but put their outputs in parallel. Drive the output LED in parallel with R8, it could be operated with only 1 mA or so as modern LEDs can be bright with only a small current.

Comment: Please see my edit. How do you think about the last version?

Comment: That avoids problem 2. Problem 2 is improved but you are at the limit of the LM339 that is only guaranteed to sink 4mA. Even then under worst case conditions (a weak 4N25) it will be difficult to get the 10V swing with a 4N25. You could use a better opto-isolator.

Comment: Thanks do you know a better model? Which parameter should I look?

Comment: @HezarFen start with a 6N136

Comment: I followed Jack Creasey's answer/suggestion it works now. In simulation I obtain what I want for the output. I also increased R7 to 10k for low current sinking. What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

### That LED is in a silly place

Your choice of location for the output LED is actually rather silly -- it's floating the emitter of the opto output up to 2V for no good reason.  Put it in *series* with the optocoupler's LED instead if it can be moved to the other side of the optocoupler and reduce R7 accordingly; if you can't, put it in series with R8.

As to reducing R7 anyway, it's probably a good idea as the 4N25 is an older, not-so-hot part, and really needs all the LED current it can get to produce a decent output.

Comment: I moved the LED between R7 and optocoupler. But to make the output work between 1V to 10V I had to reduce as you said R7 to 560. If I set R7 to 1k it doesn't work, but 560  Ohm works. Secondly, if I put LED in series with R8 I still have to reduce R7 around 560 Ohm. It is okay the output but do you think setting R7 to 560 Ohm? Please see my edit I uploaded the version with your suggestions.